# Attached Properties don't work with Tab Control DataContextChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

Here's a problem with attached property when it comes to Tab Control.

Here's a user control:

```
public partial class ContentControlInstant : UserControl
{
    public ContentControlInstant()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoadedEvent;
        //DataContextChanged += OnDataContextEventChanged; //the attached property binding doesn't work if I set the binding at the DataContextChanged event?
    }

    private void OnDataContextEventChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var printerHehe = "Printer BB";
            ExtraProperties.SetPrinter(this, printerHehe);
        }
    }

    private void OnLoadedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var printerHehe = "Printer HAHAHA";
        ExtraProperties.SetPrinter(this, printerHehe);
    }


}
```

And this is how I define my `ExtraProperties`

```
 public static class ExtraProperties
   {

   public static readonly DependencyProperty PrinterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
       "Printer", typeof(String), typeof(ExtraProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(String)));

   public static String GetPrinter(DependencyObject obj)
   {
       return (String)obj.GetValue(PrinterProperty);
   }

   public static void SetPrinter(DependencyObject obj, String value)
   {

       obj.SetValue(PrinterProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public class ContentControlVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();


        }
    }

    private string _printer;

    public string Printer
    {
        get => _printer;
        set
        {
            _printer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public string TabHeader { get; }
    public ContentControlVM(string tabHeader, string name)
    {
        TabHeader = tabHeader;
        Name = name;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

public class MainWindowVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public TabbedExcelVM TabbedExcelVM { get;}
    public ContentControlVM ContentControlVM { get;}

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        TabbedExcelVM =new TabbedExcelVM();
        ContentControlVM = new ContentControlVM("Separate", "Separate Name");


    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}




public class TabbedExcelVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

     public IEnumerable<ContentControlVM> Tabs { get; }

     public TabbedExcelVM()
     {
         var tabs = new List<ContentControlVM>();
         tabs.Add(new ContentControlVM("AA", "Name AA"));
         tabs.Add(new ContentControlVM("BB", "Name BB"));
         Tabs = tabs;

     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }

     protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
         if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
         field = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
         return true;
     }
 }
```

And here's the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="AttachedPropertyBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AttachedPropertyBinding"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:AttachedPropertyBinding.ViewModel"
        xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:AttachedPropertyBinding.UI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TabbedExcelVM}">
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
                <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeader}"/>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TabControl>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ContentControlVM}">
            <ui:ContentControlInstant 
                ui:ExtraProperties.Printer="{Binding Printer, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
            </ui:ContentControlInstant>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding TabbedExcelVM}"/>
    <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentControlVM}"/>-->
</Window>
```

What is important is that if I bind the ContentControl to a TabControl (`TabbedExcelVM`) as per the above,

The `Printer` is binded for the first `TabItem`, but not the second.

However, if I enable the line `DataContextChanged += OnDataContextEventChanged;` line, then amazingly, the binding will not happen at all! It seems that now, the attached Property `Printer` will not be binded to the underlying ViewModel `Printer` property.

Why is it happening, and how to fix this?

Comment: What is the purpose of ExtraProperties.Printer attached property? Accessing its setter in code behind may be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

There are happening two things:

1. `TabControl` renders the `TabItem` content in a shared `ContentPresenter`. There is not an individual `ContentPresenter` for each `TabItem`. This makes sense as there is only a single tab visible at a time. Unless the data type doesn't change, the `DataTemplate` (used as value for the `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate`) won't change too. Only the data bindings on the contained elements will update based on the changed data source. But, in your case, this means that because you have configured the `Binding` on the `ExtraProperties.Printer` attached property to operate as `BindingMode.OneWayToSource`, the `Binding` is only evaluated once - for the first data model. Remember, the first data model changes the presented data type of the `ContentPresenter` from `null` to `ContentControlVM`. This causes the `DataTemplate` to be loaded, which creates the reused instance of `ContentControlInstant`, which causes the Loaded event to be raised. Now, when switching between tabs, the same `ContentControlInstant` instance is used because the `DataTemplate` is reused and only the `Binding` objects are updated. And because you have configured the `Binding` to the `Printer` property as `OneWayToSource` nothing is going to happen - the target, `ContentControlInstant` instance, has not changed and therefore the `Binding` won't update the source (i.e. update source trigger is not satisfied).

   You can fix this by using the `TabControl` properly. Usually, you have similar tab headers but a completely different tab content. You can express this by modifying the data structure: the `TabItem` model must contain a property for the data model (composition) that can be assigned to the `TabControl.Content` property. If you don't do this, then the `TabItem` is implicitly assigned to the `TabControl.Content` property.

   The following simple example designs a data model for a two tab `TabControl`: `FirstTabContentItem` and `SecondTabContentItem`. Because each `TabControl.Content` value is now of a different type, a new `DataTemplate` is loaded. In your case a new instance of `ContentControlInstant` will be created each time, which would trigger the `OneWayToSource` `Binding` to update the source:

**TabItemModel.cs**

```cs
class TabItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // For complex headers create another data model used with a DataTemplate.
  // Otherwise, assign a simple string value.
  public object Header { get; set; }

  public ITabContentItem Content { get; set; }
}
```

**ITabContentItem.cs**

```cs
interface ITabContenItem
{
  string TextData { get; set; }
}
```

**FirstTabContentItem.cs**

```cs
class FirstTabContentItem : ITabContentItem
{}
```

**SecondTabContentItem.cs**

```cs
class SecondTabContentItem : ITabContentItem
{}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>
    {
      new TabItem() { Header = "Tab #1", Content = new FirstTabContentItem() { TextData = "Content #1" }},
      new TabItem() { Header = "Tab #2", Content = new SecondTabContentItem() { TextData = "Content #2" }},
    }
  }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FirstTabContentItem}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextData}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SecondTabContentItem}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextData}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Header"
              Value="{Binding Header}" />
      <Setter Property="Content"
              Value="{Binding Content}" />
    </Style>
  </Wndow.Resources>

  <TabControl ItemsSource={Binding TabItems}" />
</Window>
```

2. The second effect you are experiencing is that you clear the `Binding` when setting the attached property. In WPF the dependency property system uses a priority system known as [Dependency property precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-8.0#dependency-property-precedence-list). From the list you can see that local values have a very high precedence. Only animations and property coercion have a higher precedence. Assigning a local value always overwrites previous values (except the value comes from an animation or coerce callback), for example:

```cs
// Overwrites previous values including binding expressions
ExtraProperties.SetPrinter(this, printerHehe);
```

In your case the previous value was a binding expression. Because the `Binding` is now cleared, your XAML code does no longer behave as expected.

To fix it, define the dependency property to bind `TwoWay` by default (by configuring the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` object) or explicitly configure the `Binding` to operate in `TwoWay` mode.
Then use the `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue` method to set a value while bypassing the value precedence list. `OneWay` and `OneWayToSource` do not allow to preserve the previous value e.g. the `Binding` expression, as the dependency property system will use the binding source as value cache):

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty PrinterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "Printer", 
  typeof(String), 
  typeof(ExtraProperties), 
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    default(String), 
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

private void OnDataContextEventChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.NewValue != null)
  {
    var printerHehe = "Printer BB";
    SetCurrentValue(ExtraProperties.PrinterProperty, printerHehe);
  }
}
```

```xml
<ui:ContentControlInstant ui:ExtraProperties.Printer="{Binding Printer}" />
```

Comment: *In your case the previous value was a binding expression. Because the Binding is now cleared, your XAML code does no longer behave as expected.* Here' something that I don't understand, I thought that `ExtraProperties.SetPrinter(this, printerHehe);` is just setting the attached property `Printer`. If I don't have this statement, then the attached property `Printer` will be a null, so how can it be clearing the binding expression? if it's indeed to be clearing the binding expression whenever we involve setting the attached property `Printer`, then how can we populate that value at all?

Comment: Becauuse this XAML assigns a binding to the attached property: `<ui:ContentControlInstant ui:ExtraProperties.Printer="{Binding Printer, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />`. Now when you set  this value from inside the control you override the previous value. It's obvious if the value was e.g., an integer. But in this case the value is the binding expression.

Comment: This is a common behavior for dependency properties. That's what the `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue` method is for. It behaves different from `DepedencyObject.SetValue` in that it allows to restor the previous value. `SetCurentValue` can be viewed as assigning a temporary value. And `ExtraProperties.SetPrinter` is just a wrapper around `DependencyObject.SetValue`.

Comment: *"then how can we populate that value at all?"* - Avoid OneWayToSource for dependency properties when your control will modify the property internally. In that case define the property a TwoWay by default (like in the above example). Use `SetCurrentValue` to modify the property internally if you don't meant to "overwrite" the value.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-8.0#setcurrentvalue

Comment: This is from the SetCurrentValue() Remarks section *"This method is used by a component that programmatically sets the value of one of its own properties without disabling an application's declared use of the property. The SetCurrentValue method changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will continue to work."*